# MS Project Calendar

Tags: ms-project, tasks, tracking, ms-project-2016

I'm new MS Project user; I'm trying to sync my Ms Project 2016 calendar with Outlook 2013, I want tasks due dates give notification in Outlook. How can I do that?

Comment: Is your organization using Project Server 2013 or 2010?  If so, your Project Server administrator would need to make some configuration changes to allow for synchronizing project tasks between Project and Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way out of the box to directly import Microsoft Project tasks into Outlook. There used to be an Outlook Add-in for Project Server 2007 and an Exchange Sync for Project Server 2010/2013. All of those have been deprecated since.

There are some third-party add-ons that can do what you want, the only one I have implemented is [Allocatus](https://www.allocatus.com/).

From personal experience, I can tell you that everyone wants a Project/Outlook integration, until they actually get it. Project and Outlook don't work on the same level, Outlook tasks and appointments are usually more detailed and have more accurate scheduling than tasks in Project. Tasks in Project are linked to each other while tasks in Outlook are not. Those two tools don't have compatible logic. This leads to intense frustration when you move something in Outlook, and this in return wreaks complete havoc in your Project plan, for example. Or if you only import tasks from Project, but don't sync back, you have accurate information for a day and a half until you don't know which date is valid anymore. If there is a product on the market that handles all these issues gracefully, I haven't encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it :

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_project-mso_other/microsoft-project-and-outlook-sync/37bbc611-8495-4487-a4f5-27a56a133658

If you use project server then :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-and-set-up-the-Microsoft-Office-Project-Add-in-for-Outlook-4fe87c04-c6f0-4995-bf56-e44858a5ae51?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Allocatus](https://www.allocatus.com/) at a previous company I worked at and thought it would be helpful. As I mentioned in my comments, it automatically updates your calendar to a to-do list form in MS Project. I believe it can also do this in the reverse direction but we didn't use that feature.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this software as it should do what you are trying to achieve.

https://www.allocatus.com/

It synchronizes MS Project with a calendar or to-do list and automatically sends updates.
I hope it helps.

Comment: While this links to something that appears to be tangentially responsive, it looks a lot like spam. If you're affiliated with the product, say so. More importantly, you should explain *how* your link solves the problem, rather just linking to something and saying it does.